# Can I make a ERC20 transer after receiving and before N confirmations?

Tags: erc-20

Let's suppouse **A** user send tokens to **B** user. It may be hard to consider it to be confirmed yet. At this point **B** send the tokens received to another address. Could this transaction be successful? Is there any solution to increase the probability of success for the second transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have:

- T<sub>a</sub>: **A** send *K* tokens to **B**, signed by **A**.
- T<sub>b</sub>: **B** send *J* tokens to **C**, signed by **B**.

Since the transactions T<sub>a</sub> and T<sub>b</sub> are frow two different addresses the miners do not have to process them in order.

Even if **B** waits for enough confirmation there's nothing that prohibit miners to cause a chain reorganization. Waiting for lots of confirmations gives you a very high probability that it will not occur.